# Jmeter - Error Handling when assertion text failed

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

I have below requests in Jmeter, For the Search ID in Action I am verifying the assertion text. I want to implement that when I do not find assertion text, Jmeter script will not perform the next request instead it should go to Vuser_End i.e. Logout request. I need Logout action to be performed mandatory after assertion fail for a particular request but not interested to run all the requests after assertion failed. Could you please suggest me with some examples?

Vuser_Init(Once Only Controller)
--HomePage
--Login

Action(Loop Controller)
--Search the ID
--Create the ID.
-- Etc.

Vuser_End(Once Only Controller)
--Logout

Answer (score 1):

Put your conditional logic (i.e. "Create the ID" and so on) under the [If Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/six-tips-for-jmeter-if-controller-usage) and use [`${JMeterThread.last_sample_ok}` pre-defined variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#predefinedvars) as the condition:

[image]

Given the above configuration `Create the ID` request will be executed only if "Search ID" sampler is successful. If you need to set custom pass/fail criteria for the "Search ID" sampler - go for [Response Assertion](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Response_Assertion)